# symfony2 cache first time slow for all routes

Tags: php, apache, symfony, caching

In symfony2 project, One of my route is /vendor. After cache warm up it takes about 4 secs for this page to load after which the page comes from the cache. It takes less than 100ms for the /route to be processed when the page is found in the cache.

Here is the real problem. Every subsequent route, say /vendor/1 or /vendor/1/edit take lot of time for the first time. If I am rendering lots of vendors on the /vendor page then it is a nightmare to click all the links for the first time.

I am using the following cache parameters for the controller. 
**Question**: How to set cache so that all the links in /vendor are found in the cache so that /vendor/1 /vendor/2 /vendor/3 /vendor/{id} can all be processed fast?

```
/**
 * Vendor controller.
 *
 * @Route("/vendor")
 * @Cache(expires="tomorrow", public=true, smaxage="36000", maxage="36000")
 */
Age:0
Cache-Control:max-age=3600, public, s-maxage=36000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:1854
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 31 Jul 2015 15:16:15 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11
X-Content-Digest:en11c12a9aefabc2c0cc106e0b632e46f26bdf5f004618f501912a005ef058b7b6
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.11
X-Symfony-Cache:GET /vendor/2: **stale, invalid, store**
```

Answer (score 1):

The cache warmup is not for HTTP cache. It is the php cache (compiling configurations etc etc)

If you want to warm up your HTTP cache you need to write a script that access those URLs.

What you should be more concerned about is why it takes 4 seconds when you access a page that is not in cache. Try to profile with Blackfire and see whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I had to clear my browser cache and cookies and all the responses are now getting "fresh".

Looks like if I do some change to the cache settings then the whole cache gets invalid and I need to start afresh.

I am not sure whether it is the right reasoning but it sure is working for me now. for the time being.